# How to loop for values in an array and concatenate extra values to it?

Tags: groovy

I want to perform a clever way and not a hard coded way to loop through each cost value of an array and be able to concatenate the value `0000` to the cost value.

I have tried using a `.each` but a for loop before that but had no luck so wanted to know how this can be achieved?

Below is what I have tried:

```
def cost = [20, 25, 40, 50]

log.error cost.findAll { it.value+'0000' }
```

and

```
def cost = [20, 25, 40, 50]

for(def i in cost) {
    i + '0000'
}

log.error cost
```

So I want the cost values to be:

```
200000
250000
400000
500000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `collect`:

```
[20, 25, 40, 50].collect { "${it}0000" }
```

Also it would be better to use formatter or multiply these values instead of just suffixing them with zeros.

Also `each` won't work since the logic is executed to every single element on the list but the original collection remains untouched, as with `for`.